# small doubt about Percentage formula

Tags: percentages

In many places I have seen formula to calculate $x$ % of amount $A$ given as $\frac{x}{100}\times A$.

But I feel writing this way doesn't explains what we are actually computing.

What I have understood by $x$ % of $A$ is first we have to divide $A$ into hundred equal parts i.e. we look for one hundredth part of $A$, and then scale it by $x$.

So may be writing $\frac{A}{100} \times x$ well explains $x$ % of $A$.

Although both are similar, I prefer to write second one. Is my logic correct or the first one also has some reasoning?

Comment: The expressions are equivalent.  Use whichever one you like.  This seems like a matter of opinion to me.

Comment: As "%" is an abbreviation for "${}\cdot\frac{1}{100}$", it's just a different representation of a fraction.  Consider $\frac58$ of $24$, that is $\frac58\cdot24$.  You divide $24$ in $8$ parts and then multiply by $5$:  $$\frac58\cdot24=\frac{24}{8}\cdot5.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We would like to know what amount equals $x\%$ of quantity $A.$

- $(\frac{x}{100}\times A)$ determines the answer by first converting
  the percentage into a fraction.
- $(\frac{A}{100} \times x)$ first determines what $1\%$ of the
  quantity is, then scales that according to the given percentage.

Both expressions give the same correct answer.